# What is this notation used for combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

So I'm currently taking a combinatorics course and have often seen the following notation:

$$\binom{n+r-1}{r}$$

I'm not quite sure how or when this formula should be used. 
I'm used to the normal formula for either combinations or permutations but where is the $-1$ coming from and how do I know when to use it instead of the usual cases?

Comment: Well, I'm sure this expression comes up all over the place, but [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) leaps to mind first.

Comment: [Stars and Bars Theorem ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This notation usually denotes a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). The most common form to see them is
$$
\binom{n}{k}
$$
the notation you have shown here is the same, but you can replace $n$ with $n+r-1$ and $k$ with $r$. There is a formula to calculate this coefficient given by
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$
so in your case you have 
$$
\binom{n+r-1}{r} = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n+r-1-r)!} = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}
$$
the exact reason why there is a $-1$ will depend on the question you are answering. This probably relates to a [multiset coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) which can also be expressed using double brackets
$$
\binom{n+r-1}{r} = \left(\!\!\binom{n}{r}\!\!\right)
$$
which has meaning "The number of multisets of cardinality r, with elements taken from a finite set of cardinality n".